# Animation - "Toss" Add to Cart Animation is available in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

Is anyone developed animation like the following in flutter? When we click on that add to cart that transition kind animation I need. Let me know if any plugin is available for this. Appreciate for your help. https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/OJPdZxg

DEMO:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addtocart').on('click',function(){
    
    var button = $(this);
    var cart = $('#cart');
    var cartTotal = cart.attr('data-totalitems');
    var newCartTotal = parseInt(cartTotal) + 1;
    
    button.addClass('sendtocart');
    setTimeout(function(){
      button.removeClass('sendtocart');
      cart.addClass('shake').attr('data-totalitems', newCartTotal);
      setTimeout(function(){
        cart.removeClass('shake');
      },500)
    },1000)
  })
})
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.page-wrapper button {
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  background: #d5d8e7;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #292d48;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.page-wrapper button .cart-item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}
.page-wrapper button .cart-item:before {
  content: '1';
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #2bd156;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.page-wrapper button.sendtocart .cart-item {
  display: block;
  animation: xAxis 1s forwards cubic-bezier(1, 0.44, 0.84, 0.165);
}
.page-wrapper button.sendtocart .cart-item:before {
  animation: yAxis 1s alternate forwards cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #292d48;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cart i {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}
.cart:before {
  content: attr(data-totalitems);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  background: #2bd156;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 24px;
  min-width: 24px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
.cart.shake {
  animation: shakeCart 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes xAxis {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(50vw - 105px));
  }
}
@keyframes yAxis {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-50vh + 75px));
  }
}
@keyframes shakeCart {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(6px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-4px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart" class="cart" data-totalitems="0">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</div>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <button id="addtocart">
    Add to Cart
    <span class="cart-item"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
double x,y;
  @override
  void initState() {
    x =0;
    y =0;
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      vsync: this,
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      
          child: Container(
        child: ButtonTheme(
            buttonColor: Colors.blue,
            child: Stack(children: [
              AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _animationController,
                child: Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, top: 4),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: new Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                        child: new Text(
                          '1',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          x+=100;
                          y+=100;
                          _animationController.forward();


                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return Transform.translate(
                    offset: (Offset(x,y)),
                    child: child);
                },
              ),
            ])),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

With the help of AnimationController, Stack and Transition widgets, the above animation can be done. We move the widget from one location to another by specifying the coordinates (if it possible without the coordinates that also will be fine)

[image: Image before animation]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sidekick

and

https://pub.dev/packages/local_hero

My keyword is 'hero' for https://pub.dev/

Comment: will check it and update you..I need like that jumping transition animation

Answer (score 0):

solution based on video that I have found there https://morioh.com/p/ecb172b5de54

```
class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
     
  @override
  _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState();
}

class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController moveController;
  late Animation moveAnimation;

  Position? fromPosition;
  GlobalKey starKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    moveController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    moveAnimation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: moveController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);

    moveController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        print('end of animation');
        setState(() {
          fromPosition = null;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    moveController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fromKey = GlobalKey();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
                Container(child: Icon(Icons.weekend, key: fromKey)),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        fromPosition = getPositionByKey(fromKey);
                      });
                      moveController.reset();
                      moveController.forward();
                    },
                    child: Text('start animation')),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Spacer(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      buildFlyWidget(),
                      Container(
                          width: 24,
                          height: 24,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child:
                              Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.black)),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildFlyWidget() {
    if (fromPosition == null) {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
    return Container(
      key: starKey,
      height: 24,
      width: 24,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: moveAnimation,
        builder: (context, child) {
          Position currentPosition;
          double x = 0, y = 0;
          if (starKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() != null) {
            currentPosition = getPositionByKey(starKey);
            x = fromPosition!.x - currentPosition.x;
            y = fromPosition!.y - currentPosition.y;
          }
          if (x == 0) return Container();
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                x * (1 - moveAnimation.value), y * (1 - moveAnimation.value)),
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: fromPosition == null ? 0.0 : 1.0,
              child: Icon(Icons.weekend_outlined, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Position getPositionByKey(GlobalKey key) {
  final renderObject = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject()!;
  var translation = renderObject.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
  final rect =
      renderObject.paintBounds.shift(Offset(translation.x, translation.y));
  return Position(rect.left, rect.top, rect.size);
}

class Position {
  double x;
  double y;
  Size size;

  Position(this.x, this.y, this.size);
}
```